# SQL join multiple tables - result set not expected

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have 4 tables I want join.  Let us call them tables A, B, C, and D.  B, C, and D are all subsets of table A.  There could be some records that are common amongst B, C, and D.  My goal is to select all records in A that are not in B, C, or D.  So, I think the correct query to run is:

```
SELECT
    A.x
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.x = B.y
LEFT JOIN C
ON A.x = C.z
LEFT JOIN D
ON A.x = D.i
WHERE 
(
(B.y IS NULL)
AND
(C.z IS NULL)
AND
(D.i IS NULL)
)
```

The problem I am having is that I know that there are some records in table B that are returning in this result set which should not be.  (The same could hold for tables C and D as well.)  So, something must be wrong with my query.  My best guess is that the joins are vague.  The first one should give me all records in A that are not in B.  Similarly, the second one should give me all records in A that are not in C.  Because I have used AND in the WHERE clause, then I should essentially be returning only the records that are common to each of the joins.  But, something is going wrong.  How do I correct this?

Comment: Your query must work. Which kind of data is stored in this data (type, domain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT x FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT x FROM
(
   SELECT y FROM B UNION
   SELECT z FROM C UNION
   SELECT i FROM D
) T(x)
```

Comment: It turns out that the query I wrote should return a correct result set.  However, because of the use of multiple ANDs with an outer join (i.e., LEFT JOIN), I need to use the join operator (+) (at least, that is the guideline for Oracle, not necessarily SQL Server).  Still, I like your query more.